# How would I determine the spanning set for the kernel of a map that sends each polynomial to its value at 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

I am given a linear transformation, T, such that T: P --> R (where P is the vector space of polynomials and R is all real numbers), and that *p*|-->*p*(0).

I know that the kernel of a transformation, T, is the set of all **u** in V such that T(**u**) = **0**

So I'm looking for the spanning set of all *p* for which T(*p*)= *p*(0) = **0**, but I'm not sure what **0** (the zero vector) looks like in this example, and I also don't know how to notate a spanning set with a polynomial.

I think of *p*(0) as the polynomial given by a(0)^0 + b(0) + c(0)^2 + ... + z(0)^n, but other than that, I feel pretty lost with finding a spanning set of the kernel of T.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that is $P$? I think you want to say $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$: vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$. I think that you refer to that vector space by the last lines of your post and not the vector space of all polynomials, $P$. Note that $\dim (P)=\infty$ and $\dim(P_{n}(\mathbb{R}))=n+1$.

Comment: Your first step is to see what the zero vector of the vector space $\Bbb R$ is. There’s only one reasonable candidate; what is it?

Comment: @Ramanujan: The OP’s $n$ in the penultimate paragraph is generic, not specific; $P$ is the space of all real polynomials.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, I understand.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott would the zero vector in the vector space R just be the real number 0?

Comment: @Ramanujan You perhaps mean to say the dimension of the space of all polynomials is $\aleph_0$. The object $\infty$ is not a priori introduced as a cardinal and at any rate we can't expect $\infty＝\aleph_0$ to be a theorem of set theory.

Comment: @HeWhoShouldNotbenamed Yes. In general, the polynomial ring in one indeterminate over any ring $A$ is formally constructed such that $A$ be a subring of it.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ You're right. That was a _lapsus brutus_.

Comment: @SatanLucifer: Yes, that’s right. And the polynomials that map to it are the ones with $0$ constant term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero element of this vector space is the zero polynomial. A spanning set for the kernel  is $\{x,x^{2},x^{3},...\}$.

[The kernel consists of all polynomials with no constant term].

Comment: This makes more sense to me, I'm still a little confused; wouldn't T(*p*) (which equals *p*(0)) equal **0** (which is the real number 0 since **0** is in R), as long as the constant term of the polynomial equals zero? (ie. if p = a(x)^0 + b(x)^1) + c(x)^2 + ... + z(x)^n, then as long as a = 0, *p*(0) = **0** = 0)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. When I say polynomial with 'no constant term' I mean  polynomials in which the constant term equals $0$. @SatanLucifer

Comment: ooooh! That makes sense! I guess my only lingering confusion is with how the spanning set for the kernel is notated; why does the span: \{x,x^{2},x^{3},...\} represent all polynomials with no constant term? Is it because \{c,x,x^{2},x^{3},...\} would represent a span that includes the constant term, so \{x,x^{2},x^{3},...\} (your answer) just implies that the constant term = 0?     (sorry for the awful formatting on my part!)

Comment: @SatanLucifer Any polynomial with constant term $0$ is of the form $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_kx^{k}$ and this is a  linear combination of the functions $\{x,x^{2},..\}$. Hence $\{x,x^{2},..\}$ spans the kernel.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications! I get it now :)))

Comment: Wasn’t OP asking what’s the zero vector in the codomain, which is the element $0\in\Bbb R$, not a polynomial?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $Tp=p(0)$. So kernel of $T$ consists of all polynomials $p$ such that $p(0)=0$.

Comment: That’s right.  But OP asked what is the zero vector of the *range* vector space, and that is $0\in\Bbb R$, not the zero polynomial —you said the zero polynomial in your answer